# Obtener el resultado del suscribe a un http observable, antes que el resto del código. Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

Estoy haciendo un trabajo desarrollo en angular, resulta que necesito inicializar unas variables con los resultados de un subscribe, pero este obtiene el resultado al cuando ya el resto ya se ejecuto. como puedo hacer que el código espere hasta que el suscribe obtenga la respuesta del servidor?

```
this.solicitudesArrendamiento2Service.retomarSolicitudArrendamiento(formConsultaSolicitudArrendamientoPN['codigo_form'],
    this.maskUtilsService.unmaskNumber(formConsultaSolicitudArrendamientoPN['identificacion_arrendatario']))
    .pipe(finalize(() => {
      this.isLoading = false;
    }))
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.solicitudArrendamiento = data[0];

        this.fecha_caducidad = new Date(this.solicitudArrendamiento.fecha_caducidad);
        if (this.solicitudArrendamiento.dias_registro_solicitud > 30 || this.fecha_caducidad < new Date()) {
          this.modalSaCaducada = true;
        } else {
          if (data.length === 0) {
            this.modalErrorConsultaCodigoForm = true;
          } else {
            this.solicitudesArrendamiento2Service.setUserData(data);
            this.router.navigate(['solicitudes_arrendamiento/actualizar_solicitud' + this.solicitudArrendamiento.tipo_solicitante],
              {
                queryParams: {
                  tipo_persona: this.solicitudArrendamiento.tipo_persona,
                  valor_canon: this.solicitudArrendamiento.Valor_Canon
                }
              });
          }
        }
      },
      error => {
        this.modalDataConsultadaNoExiste = true;
        log.error(`Consulta SA get error: ${error.message}`);
      }
    );
```

Servicio con la función que realiza la petición al servidor

```
retomarSolicitudArrendamiento(codigo_formulario: string, nro_identificacion: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${routes.base}get/${codigo_formulario}/${nro_identificacion}/`);
}
```

Gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Este hilo puede ser de tu ayuda:
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52485266/angular-rxjs-synchronous-observable)

Comment: ¿ Cual es el código que se ejecuta antes de que llegue al subcribe ? ¿ No se puede poner dentro del propio subscribe ? Quizás ayudaría tener una visión algo más global del componente

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar **async/await**.

Ejemplo:

```
async miMetodo() {

   await metodoQueInicializaVariables(); // 

   // Resto del código que quiero que se ejecute DESPUES del observable/promesa

}

metodoQueInicilizarVariables() {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

     // Tu observable

     /* Dentro del mismo, al finalizar todas las instrucciones, 
        llamas al resolve(); para que retorne la promesa. */ 

  })

}
```

Espero que te sirva!